# OR operator between javascript functions

Tags: javascript

I am debugging a complex javascript and I came across a line:

```
 (this.kq.hu || nq.hq)(uu);
```

`hu` and `hq` are both functions and `uu` is a variable(if Im correct)

I tried to find out what this line of code does for the past hour with no luck.

Does anybody know what exactly this line of code does?

I think this is something very small.. but I do not get it after giving it a thought.

You can find the full js here: http://pastebin.com/n6rXT7sf

Its line# 35

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the equivalent of this:

```
if (this.kq.hu) {
  this.kq.hu(uu);
} else {
  nq.hq(uu);
}
```

Translated: if `this.kq.hu` exists, call it with parameter `uu`, otherwise call `nq.nq` with the same parameter.

Answer (score 1):

if `(this.kq.hu === null || this.kq.hu === undefined)` function `nq.hq` will run, else `this.kq.hu` will run with parameter `uu`.